# Leaflet error when loading shapefile (shp is not defined)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, shapefile

I am following the [Leaflet essentials book](https://www.packtpub.com/eu/web-development/leafletjs-essentials), on how to load shapefiles.
The book's instructions are:

> First, add references to two JavaScript files. The first,
>   leaflet-shpfile, is the plugin, and the second depends on the
>   shapefile parser, shp.js:

```
<script src="leaflet.shpfile.js">
</script><script src="shp.js"></script>
```

> Next,
>   create a new shapefile layer and add it to the map. Pass the layer
>   path to the zipped shapefile:

```
var shpfile = new L.Shapefile('council.zip');
shpfile.addTo(map);
```

I've followed the above instructions with slight changes since I'm on Webpack. Here's what I 've done:

1. installed `shpjs` with `npm i shpjs --S`
2. downloaded `leaflet.shpfile.js` from [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile/gh-pages/leaflet.shpfile.js) and placed it in `src/`
3. in my `*.js` file I require both `shpjs` and `leaflet.shpfile.js` with the following code:

```
const shp=require('shpjs');
require('./leaflet.shpfile.js');
```

I then access the shapefile as instructed:

```
console.log(shp);
const shapeFileLayer = L.shapefile(someURL);
```

On the last line of code I get the following trace:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:196 ReferenceError: shp is not defined
    at NewClass.addFileData (leaflet.shpfile.js:38)
    at NewClass.initialize (leaflet.shpfile.js:25)
    at new NewClass (leaflet-src.js:300)
    at Object.L.shapefile (leaflet.shpfile.js:67)
    at Map.createLayerGroups (main.js_+_3_modules:342)
    at Map.componentDidMount (main.js_+_3_modules:186)
    at ik (react-dom.production.min.js:251)
    at exports.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
    at fg (react-dom.production.min.js:120)
    at Yj (react-dom.production.min.js:244)
```

The `console.log` statement on the line immediately above succeeds, showing that some function `shp` is defined. I cannot, then, explain why I get the reference error `shp is not defined` on the line that comes immediately next.

Comment: If you're using `require`, then that means you are using AMD modules, and that should be using some kind of bundling (webpack, rollup, babel, etc). What's your setup in that regard?

Comment: Note that [`leaflet.shpfile.js`](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile/blob/gh-pages/leaflet.shpfile.js) assumes that `shp` is a **global**. Maybe you can work it out with that info.

Comment: @IvanSanchez `window.shp = shp` does seem to solve this (it breaks further down the road but at least this hurdle is crossed). How were you able to deduce that `leaflet.shpfile.js` expects `shp` to be *global* ?

Comment: By the [eslint-related comment on line 3](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile/blob/5210fb500bcfe0a3d2602635bd446a79199f5f28/leaflet.shpfile.js#L3) and the references to a global `shp` on lines 14, 16 and 35. Also, Leaflet plgins of a certain era which require you to load several JS files in succession have a tendency to rely on globals or on stuff held in the `L` global.